# Why is seq(0:3) = 1 2 3 4?

Tags: r

I'm learning R, and I've got problem at seq()
I know that seq(0, 3) is 0 1 2 3.
But I don't know why seq(0:3) is 1 2 3 4.

In RDocumentation(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq), it says that

```
seq(from, to)
seq(from, to, by= )
seq(from, to, length.out= )
seq(along.with= )
seq(from)
seq(length.out= )
```

The first form generates the sequence from, from+/-1, …, to (identical to from:to).

So isn't it true that seq(0, 3) and seq(0:3) are identical?

Comment: Seeing as  `foo <- 0:3`  works all by itself, why get into that jam in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `seq(0,3)` and `seq(0:3)` are not identical. In the first case you are calling the function with the parameters (`from=` and `to=`) and in the second cause you are passing a single parameter to the function (`from=`). It doesn't matter if you pass a single value or a vector (because there are no single values in R, just vectors of length 1). Consider

```
seq(3:6)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

If you pass just one argument to `seq()` and it has a length greater than 1, it will return the sequence 1 to the length of the object. This behavior is described later in the help file

> The fifth form generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., length(from) (as if argument along.with had been specified), unless the argument is numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as 1:from (even for seq(0) for compatibility with S). Using either seq_along or seq_len is much preferred (unless strict S compatibility is essential).

The part where it says "The first form ... [is] (identical to from:to)" means that `seq(0, 3)` is the same as `0:3`, not `seq(0:3)`

You can see this behavior in the code for `seq.default`. The check for a single argument happens early in the code

```
...
if ((One <- nargs() == 1L) && !missing(from)) {
    lf <- length(from)
    return(if (mode(from) == "numeric" && lf == 1L) {
        if (!is.finite(from)) stop("'from' must be a finite number")
        1L:from
    } else if (lf) 1L:lf else integer())
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not claiming it's the most intuitive behavior, but this does match the documentation. In the case of `seq(0,3)`, this uses the first form you show above:

> The first form generates the sequence from, from+/-1, ..., to (identical to from:to).

Producing as `0 1 2 3`.

In the case of `seq(0:3)`, this uses the fifth form:

> The fifth form generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., length(from) (as if argument along.with had been specified), unless the argument is numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as 1:from (even for seq(0) for compatibility with S). Using either seq_along or seq_len is much preferred (unless strict S compatibility is essential).

`length(0:3)` is `4` so the result is sequence 1, 2, ..., 4

Answer (score -1):

When you pass `seq(0:3)` the input `0:3` is picked up by the `along.with` parameter of the function which essentially generates a sequence of length 4.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. Since the argument is passed unnamed, it still is assigned to the `from=` parameter; it just behaves similarly to how it would if it was assigned to `along.with`. The class of the value doesn't determine which argument it is assigned to.